# Reading arguments in a command?

Tags: macros, comma-separated-list

I now know that if I want to get for example the 3rd argument passed to a command, I have use `#3`. My question is if this argument is an array how can I read elements of array without a for loop?

For example when {1,2,3} is passed as the 3rd argument. How should I read second element of it?

Note: Assume that I will always get a comma separated array of constant length.

Comment: How can you read elements of a comma separated list without a loop? You can't.

Comment: @egreg: I guess, unless you know exactly how many items will be passed, all the time. That is, you know the structure of the list, and it will always be the same.

Comment: @Werner I was referring to the general problem.

Comment: @egreg, thank you, but my question is for a constant case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\firstinlist#1,#2,#3\stoplist{#1}
\def\secondinlist#1,#2,#3\stoplist{#2}
\def\thirdinlist#1,#2,#3\stoplist{#3}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
  The list has\\
  \firstinlist#1\stoplist\\
  \secondinlist#1\stoplist\\
  \thirdinlist#1\stoplist}

\begin{document}

\noindent\foo{1,2,3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A simpler definition, where the loop is performed by internal macros, is with `xparse` and LaTeX3

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\getlistitem}{mm}
 {
  \clist_item:nn { #2 } { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
  The list has\\
  \getlistitem{1}{#1}\\
  \getlistitem{2}{#1}\\
  \getlistitem{3}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\noindent\foo{1,2,3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice. How far can you go like this? Is there such a command as `\twentythirdinlist`, for instance?

Comment: @Jubobs That's more complicated because macros can have at most nine arguments. But it's doable by expanding multiple macros.

Answer (score 2):

The following could be in line with your request:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\newcounter{itemnum}
\newcommand{\mymacroA}[3]{%
  \setcounter{itemnum}{0}% Start counting from first item
  \gdef\seconditem{\relax}%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{itemnum}%
    \ifnum\value{itemnum}=2\relax
      \gdef\seconditem{##1}%
    \fi%
  }%
  \docsvlist{#3}%
}
\makeatletter
\def\extractsecond#1,#2,#3{#2}%
\newcommand{\mymacroB}[3]{%
  \gdef\seconditem{\extractsecond#3}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\mymacroA{a}{b}{1,2,3,4,5}%
\seconditem

\mymacroA{a}{b}{6,1}%
\seconditem

\mymacroA{a}{b}{123}%
\seconditem

\mymacroA{a}{b}{a,\textbf{b},c}%
\seconditem

\mymacroB{a}{b}{1,2,3}%
\seconditem

\mymacroB{a}{b}{6,1,9}%
\seconditem

\mymacroB{a}{b}{a,\textbf{b},c}%
\seconditem

\end{document}
```

The first is an implementation using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s list processing capabilities. Therefore `\mymacroA` traverses the given list and picks out the second item, storing it in `\seconditem`.

The second implementation assumes a fixed list that resembles `<first>,<second>,<third>` and picks out second, based on this fixed definition. The works since you can specify the macro's parameter text, which should patch exactly.